# Deleting cookie to logout

Tags: cookies, logout

Would be potential problems if I delete `wordpress_logged_in_47d1523b...` cookie using javascript? Is there something additional that `wp_logout` does?

Comment: It runs two functions: `wp_destroy_current_session()` and `wp_clear_auth_cookie()`. User cannot access restricted content, admin area and all that good stuff without a session. That still doesn't mean that you should mess with security features without any good reasons. What's your goal?

Comment: I want to logout users without making them go to wp-logout using js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log out the current user with [`wp_logout()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout):

I think it is much better approach. `wp_logout()` destroys current session, clears authorization cookie and call `wp_logout` action. Also, it is a pluggable function, which means can be redefined by plugins. You can miss important stuff, specially when working in combination with other plugins.

If you want to log out from JavaScript, you can execute `wp_logout()` using ajax (code not tested, just writted here as basic example):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_enqueue_scripts' );
function cyb_enqueue_scripts() 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cyb-ajax-logout', 'url_to_js_script', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'cyb-ajax-logout', 'ajax_logout_params',
        array(
            'ajax_url'     => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'logout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'cyb-logout-nonce' ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_cyb_logout', 'cyb_ajax_logout');
function cyb_ajax_logout(){
    if( check_ajax_referer( 'cyb-logout-nonce', 'logout_nonce', false ) ) {
        wp_logout();
        $reponse = array(
            'message' => __( 'You have been logged out.', 'cyb-textdomain' )
        );
        wp_send_json_success( $reponse );
    } else {
        // Ajax referer is wrong
        $reponse = array(
            'message' => __( "Unknown referer. You couldn't been logged out.", 'cyb-textdomain' )
        );
        wp_send_json_error( $reponse );
    }
}
```

And the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var data = {
        action: 'cyb_logout',
        logout_nonce: ajax_logout_params.logout_nonce
    };
    $.getJSON( ajax_logout_params.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {
        if( response.success ) {
            // User has been logged out
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was driving home thinking about how could I logout using ajax and you gave me the answer without asking it :D

Comment: Glad to help. If this answers your question, please consider to mark it as accepted answer so other users can find it easily.

Comment: Does wp_logout calls wp_die ()? Is logging out the user but returning 0. Weird

Comment: `wp_logout()` returns nothing and it doesn't call `wp_die()`. The 0 you get is from `wp_ajax_{my_action}` action. [If it returns 0, it is not working](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Error_Return_Values), very probably because the action parameter sent in the ajax request and the action registered with `add_action('wp_ajax_....)` doesn't match. Are you using the code I posted as it is or have you modified something? As I said in the answer, I didn't test the code.

Comment: I modified it, but the function executed, because the session ended after that. But nvm, I just tried again and it worked that time, thank for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something additional that wp_logout does?

As I said in my comment, WordPress runs two functions on `wp_logout`.

1. `wp_destroy_current_session()`
2. `wp_clear_auth_cookie()`

---

`wp_clear_auth_cookie()` removes all of the cookies associated with authentication. This is what you would like to do with JavaScript.

However there's also `wp_destroy_current_session()`. This function remove the current session token from the database which brings us to the next question..

> Would be potential problems if I delete
>   wordpress_logged_in_47d1523b... cookie using javascript?

No, there could not be any problems because users can manually delete sessions and cookies but that doesn't break the web. As long as you delete the right session, everything works as you planned.

Now you might be wondering: what about session token in database? That doesn't matter anymore because session is destroyed. It will be overwritten by new token as soon as user logs in again.

---

**And now the bad news:** How are you going to delete the session with only JavaScript? Session key and value are both generated, you have no way to target the right one only with JavaScript. Session key and value are different for every user and for every session.

Comment: The good news: Regular Expressions :P